# Codeacademy error on JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Hei

I am going through the JavaScript tutorial on Codeacademy and I'm stuck on Introduction to Objects II lesson 2/30. The code that I have entered seems fine to me and the code prints the necessary line hello to the console.

But I get an error "Oops, try again. It looks like 'Hello!' wasn't logged to the console. Make sure that you properly defined the method and that you didn't change any of the provided code."

I cant seem to find anything wrong with this code that I have entered

```
function Person(job, married) {
  this.job = job;
  this.married = married;
  // add a "speak" method to Person!
  this.speak = function() {
      console.log("Hello");
  };
}

var user = new Person("Codecademy Student",false);
user.speak();
```

[image]

Comment: I copied your code into chrome console, it works fine

Comment: Ha, thats strange maybe something is wrong in Codeacademy.

Comment: Computers take everything very literally. Did you omit an exclamation point after 'Hello' ?

Comment: OMG, seriously that was the problem!. Codeacademy should fix this there was no error in the code!

Thanks by the way

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your posted image, see the last line of the code editor:

```
user.speak();z //<-- z is not something what you have defined.
```

Comment: @S4M1R, do try alert() instead of console.log() for a while and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I went through several courses on Codeacademy. Codeacademy often has broken lessons, and if it's working on jsFiddle, it's likely two things.

**1:** Spelling and punctuation. Codeacademy is very specific with strings. One wrong letter, or one wrongly punctuated letter will show it as a fail.

**2:** Error. If this is the case, the codeacademy community usually has work arounds. If not, you can skip this particular lesson, and keep on going with the course. The 100% complete is more symbolic than anything else. As long as you're learning the concepts, it's find to skip whatever you have to.

Also, codeacademy has an excellent community that will give more specific advice tailored to the course. Here's the relevant forum for that course.

http://www.codecademy.com/forums/objects-ii/0